# TextMate - How to install a bundle?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I see a lot of bundles here I'd like to get my hands on

http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/

The problem is I don't know how to install them. I've read the section 5 of manual dedicated to bundles, but there's no example how to install those from SVN.

I see the existing ones have the extension .tmbundle, but those on SVN are done differently.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try installing the bundle "GetBundles". It will help you pick new bundles in a nice GUI. I've been using it myself and it's definitely better than manually installing bundles.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
cd !$
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Then, go to "Bundles" - "GetBundles" - "Get Bundles". ([source](http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate/))

Alternatively, you can just put your `.tmbundles` into `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`, as you may have seen from the code above.

Comment: Thanks for this. It sure is nicer :) I wonder why it doesn't come by default.

Comment: Well, TextMate hasn't seen too many updates in the last months/years. Maybe something better will come in version 2, whenever it may arrive :)

Comment: I hear a lot of folks are jumping ship to Sublime. It does seem to be a nice editor but TextMate is very entrenched so not sure what will happen.

Comment: I don't miss a lot about TextMate, so I'm fine with it. Sublime looks nice though. @matt

Answer (score 13):

Download a bundle by going to its page, e.g. https://github.com/textmate/matlab.tmbundle and clicking the *Download ZIP* button.

Unzip it.

Change the name of the folder from

```
matlab.tmbundle-master
```

to

```
matlab.tmbundle
```

Now you can open it.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just download them and double click to install, as long as the extension reads tmbundle, that's how I do it.

Comment: Here's what I was looking for immediately before feeling silly for not having tried it. Also I had to read your username 3 times before realizing it didn't say Mangopoop.